# Why I to use java proxy if getDeclaredMethod is enough

Tags: java, proxy

I implement a ruby-like send method in java, I think it has implemented dynamic invoke, **my question** is does I still need java dynamic proxy?

this is my code:

```
/**
 * Created by roroco on 12/8/14.
 */
final class C {
    public void methInC(String arg) {
        System.out.println(arg + "\t\t" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getFileName() + ":" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
    }
}

class C2 {
    C c;

    public C2() {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void send(String methName, Object... args) {
        try {
            ArrayList types = new ArrayList();
            for (Object o : args) {
                types.add(o.getClass());
            }
            Class[] klsColl = (Class[]) types.toArray(new Class[]{});
            C.class.getDeclaredMethod(methName, klsColl).invoke(new C(), args);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you still need it to do what?

Comment: @chrylis i means my way has implement dynamic invoke meth, is java proxy still usefull or not?

Comment: Are you talking about just learning, or are you asking about real-world use?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic proxies are used to provide implementation for interfaces which can be passed to other code that is expecting those interfaces.